# How to close html tags in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, tidy

I'm taking html content out of my database and displaying it on a page.

Unfortunately these pages often have unclosed html tags and cause problems later when the page is rendered.

I was wondering if there is a JavaScript implementation of something like [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Basically some software which can preferably close html tags in a string.

**Edit:** I'm not in a browser environment (node.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you tagged your question with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js):

```
npm install tidy
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used the sanitizer node module as I had trouble installing that one. Regardless I think this answer is the most accurate for future readers and all suggestions were useful.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could work:

```
function tidy(htmldata) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = htmldata;
    return d.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention I'm not in a browser environment.

Comment: Beautiful. Anyone know of any browsers that won't do the magical closing?

Comment: This doesn't close tags.

Comment: @xr280xr Really? Because it does for me!

Comment: No...I don't know what happened. My bad. :$

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer balances tags.

Comment: Which is also available as [tag:node.js] module [`sanitizer`](https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer)

Comment: Thanks guys. Sanitizer as a node.js module was more useful to my solution.

Comment: @JuicyScripter, Great.  I had no idea.